# In CakePHP 3.x how can I count the number of rows in a MySql table?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I have a MYSQL table called 'devices'.  I've successfully done the bin/cake bake all.  In fact I have the auto-built DevicesController.php fully working.  But I can't figure out how to count the rows in a table.  I've tried:

```
$conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$numRows = $conn->execute('select count(*) from devices');
```

and

```
$this->DeviceSetups = TableRegistry::get('Devices');
$numRows = $this->Devices->query('select count(*) from devices'); // both like this
$numRows = $this->Devices->query('select count(*) from devices')->execute();  // and like this
```

and

```
$this->DeviceSetups = TableRegistry::get('Devices');
$numRows = $this->Devices->find('count');
```

Going thru mysql_query() isn't really a good idea because I have all the access info already setup in app.php for CakePHP to use.  I tried something else using AnyModel that didn't work.

The former 2 attempts return a Cake\Database\Statement\MysqlStatement not an integer with the number of rows in the table.  I've consulted [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxmeCPz9PPAhUK4CYKHY2UC_sQFggoMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F26312583%2Fcakephp-3-raw-sql-query&usg=AFQjCNGDYeQ4F-IRx-617w2SQHjp6ne5lQ&sig2=fUcZAhC2e06Zin2VZfcMbw) answer and [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjxmeCPz9PPAhUK4CYKHY2UC_sQFgg2MAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F22497923%2Fhow-to-write-sql-query-in-cakephp&usg=AFQjCNFQhU3GQUciLEnymeROfCj99i2aTQ&sig2=S6iEnzooGpUua2-qsAgd3Q) answer and read the CakePHP docs.  Nothing seems to tell me how to count up a table nor how to execute a raw My SQL command string and then access the result.

Comment: If your db table is called `devices`, then table class name/alias should normally be `Devices`, not `DeviceSetups`!? Apart from that it's `find()->count()`, there is no `count` finder. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records** | **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-count-of-results**

Comment: Thx, yes that was a typo.  I always change a few things to make sure my development stays proprietary.  In this case I had it sort of in the middle between changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TableRegistry::get('DeviceSetups')->find()->count();`

See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-count-of-results.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count in table then it should be like below.

```
   $count = $this->find()->count();
   echo $count;
```